# Does a function need to be declared as asynchronous to return a promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, synchronous

I'm using a helper function (`fetchGet`) returning an asynchronous function that returns a promise (`fetchWrapper`).
Does this helper function need to be declared as asynchronous to itself return a promise?

My case here is using fetch, which needs to be awaited in my first function `fetchWrapper` (simplified here for readibility):

```
// returns a promise
async function fetchWrapper(url, method) {
  const response = await fetch(url, {method: method});
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
  }
  return response;
}

async function fetchGet(url) {
  return fetchWrapper(url, 'GET');
}

async function getSpecificData() {
  return fetchGet('/a/specific/url');
}
```

Do I need to declare the `fetchGet` function as an asynchronous function as above, for it to return the promise?

Or could I just declare it as a normal synchronous function as below?
(that would be indeed the same case for the `getSpecificData` function)

```
function fetchGet(url) {
  return fetchWrapper(url, 'GET');
}
```

Comment: `async` functions automatically returns a promise if none is returned in your code (regardless what your code is returning, it will wrap the result in a promise).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does a function need to be declared as asynchronous to return a promise?

No, not at all. In fact, promises were around long before `async` functions.

Your wrapper can be just:

```
function fetchGet(url) {
  return fetchWrapper(url, 'GET');
}
```

You don't need `async` if you're not using `await` inside the function. You might *choose* to have it in order to flag up the asynchronous nature of the function, e.g., as in-code documentation (code hints in IDEs, etc.). But it isn't required.

---

Side note: You have a problem with `fetchWrapper`. It **succeeds** with the fulfillment value `undefined` if there's an HTTP error. That means code using it has to check the fulfillment value to see if it's `undefined` before using it. I'd recommend making HTTP errors errors (rejections):

```
async function fetchWrapper(url, method) {
  const response = await fetch(url, {method: method});
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
  }
  return response;
}
```

Comment: "*Otherwise, you don't need it.*" a subjective reason to use it is that `async` makes it clear which function is async. You only need to look at the signature, not check what the code does. In fact, with OP's code `fetchGet` would be async but you have to follow the function call inside it to see that. I have no doubt there are automated tools that will be able to extract signatures for you, so you don't even need to find the code yourself, which means it's even easier to see which is which.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you're right with my clunky fetchWrapper, I over-simplified it. I edit with your concise alternative

Answer (score 1):

> Does this helper function need to be declared as asynchronous to itself return a promise?

No.

`async` functions always return promises, even if the `return` statement returns something that is not a promise. `async` functions let you manage other promises inside them using `await`

You can explicitly return a promise from any function.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to declare a function as `async` when inside the function you going to await for a result, so both:

```
// returns a Promise because it's async (resolved with 'value')
async function fetchGet(url) {
  const value = await fetchWrapper(url, 'GET');
  return value;
}

// returns a Promise because fetchWrapper is a Promise
function fetchGet(url) {
  return fetchWrapper(url, 'GET');
}

// returns a Promise, just because it's async
async function fetchGet(url) {
   // nothing
}

// returns undefined
function fetchGet(url) {
    // nothing 
}
```

Work exactly the same for these callers:

```
fetchGet('url').then(value => {...})
const value = await fetchGet(url)
```